# Server doesn‘t work with sail and redis simultaneously

Tags: laravel, docker, redis

When i turn on some windows features for redis, because without them server decline access, i cant run docker server. I run sail up and can‘t access page . What could i do?

I  already changed port and tried some popular solitons.